# firstprivate clause in OpenMP does not work

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, synchronization, openmp

I have a loop which operate with class objects and functions. Also it calculate several sum values. I've try to parallel it with OpenMP:

```
    Network  net = *m_pNetwork;
    TrainingSet tran = trainingSet;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:MSE, incorrectEntries) firstprivate(tran, net) lastprivate(net) private(outputIdx)  
    for (int i = 0; i < tran.size(); i++)
    {    
        net->Evaluate(tran[i].m_inputs);
        Backpropagate(tran[i].m_expectedOutputs);

        // Check all outputs from neural network against desired values
        bool resultCorrect = true;
        for (outputIdx = 0; outputIdx < net->m_numOutputs; outputIdx++)
        {
            if (net->m_clampedOutputs[outputIdx] != tran[i].m_expectedOutputs[outputIdx])
            {
                resultCorrect = false;
            }
            MSE += pow((net->m_outputNeurons[outputIdx] - tran[i].m_expectedOutputs[outputIdx]), 2);
        }       
        if (!resultCorrect)
        {
            //#pragma omp atomic
            incorrectEntries++;
        }
    }

    *m_pNetwork = net;
```

My problem is the sum values are the same each iterations. So what i've not properly done?

Comment: `net` is a pointer. In a parallel section, each thread has its own copy of `net`, however, they all point to the same object. Is `Network::evaluate` thread-safe?

Comment: @DanielLangr yep that's stupid mistake sorry. Now I've replaced Network * net = m_pNetwork ----> Network  net = *m_pNetwork. New problem: sum values are the same each iterations.

Comment: No idea what these sum values are. However, note that now, `net` will be after parallel loop set to a single private `net` of the thread that run the last iteration. Is it what you want? (See `lastprivate` docs.)

Comment: @DanielLangr same values without lastprivate clause too

Comment: Programming by trying and observing whether it works isn't in my opinion the best approach. Read some good book about OpenMP, or its documentation, or some tutorials before using it.

Comment: @DanielLangr my problem now in a variable "net" declaration. With pointer declaration sequential algorithm worked true, now it works like parallel: same sum values all the times.

Comment: I have never seen a variable being both declared as `firstprivate` and `lastprivate` and this may very well not be legit... although I can't find a doc that explicitly allows or forbids it. `lastprivate` is in any case not much used, as the value copied back will be the one from the last thread to complete. Which thread that will be is something one usually does not control.

Comment: You don't need the `atomic` clause to increment `incorrectEntries` as it is declared with a `reduction` data-sharing attribute (i.e. there is a private copy of the variable in each thread, and all will be safely summed at the end).

Comment: parallel firstprivate lastprivate should work, but is best avoided, if only to achieve expected performance.  For omp simd, firstprivate isn't available.  Intel's legacy directives from prior to omp simd used to support it but firstprivate lastprivate has been dropped on the way to requiring OpenMP standard usage.